# Solidity long string constants over multiple lines

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Just wondering if there is a way to split long strings over more than one line in solidity?  I can't find any kind of line continuation character, and  compile error is thrown if you try to use two lines like this.  Concatenating strings appears to be complex as well

```
 string memory s = "This is a very long line of text which I would like to split over
 several lines";
```

Concatenating strings appears to be complex as well.  Do I just have to put the very long string on a very long line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can split the value to multiple separate string literals, each on one line.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    string s = "This is a very "
        "long line of text "
        "which I would like to split "
        "over several lines";
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/types.html#string-literals-and-types

---

If you want to concatenate multiple strings, you can use the `abi.encodePacked()` method returning `bytes` array, and then cast the `bytes` back to `string`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    string s1 = "Lorem";
    string s2 = "ipsum";
    
    function foo() external view returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(s1, " ", s2));
    }
}
```

Edit: Since v0.8.12, you can also use `string.concat()` (that was not available in previous versions).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract MyContract {
    string s1 = "Lorem";
    string s2 = "ipsum";

    function foo() external view returns (string memory) {
        return string.concat(s1, " ", s2);
    }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#the-functions-bytes-concat-and-string-concat